# Is it possible to change the text of the Facebook button like "okay, watch video" as like in SocialCam app?

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api

I have seen "okay,watch Video" on social cam app but still did not get where to change it. Where can I change it?

Answer (score -1):

i suppose it is a button that run OpenGraph action , not the ordinary Like button

Comment: Ya but where to find.I am using the open graph but havent been able to change it :(

Comment: posting by Open Graph you can use the button (or image) of your own ,not the Like button ... see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/ look for     <input type="button" value="Cook" onclick="postCook()" />

Comment: I guess he wants something like this https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-PLhR4J5tm8o/T7ZYVfXFbzI/AAAAAAAAAQo/Wo9UT_aLQ40/s640/permission.jpg